# Using QtWebSockets - can't connect to echoserver

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, socket.io, qt5

This question corresponds to this [QtWebSockets](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebsockets/source/d00327c971abe4c44c3c3395840be179f24c6839%3a) implementation.

I am trying to include websockets server functionality in a bigger qt-based project.

I have cloned the repo above and built the library as well as the example applications (release mode). Among the examples there is an `echoserver` and an `echoclient`. After built i start the `echoserver`, which seems to be successful (on terminal i see: `Echoserver listening on port 1234`). Then i start the `echoclient`, which exits immediately (no printout on the console). The server console does not show any signs of detecting connection attempts. The server listens on `0.0.0.0:1234` (checked with `netstat`). The client tries to connect on `"ws://localhost:1234/"`.

I modified the `echoclient` example to connect to `echo.websocket.org` and rebuilt it. After starting the client it connects successfully and the sent message is echoed back.

I created a simple html file with a websocket client trying to connect to the `echoserver` and opened it with a browser. This again cannot connect to the server (works with echo.websocket.org).

Environment:

- Ubuntu 13.10(64bit) running as a virtualbox guest on a win7 machine.
- Qt5.2(64bit)

I thought that this is something to do with the virtualbox networking settings, so i repeated the whole thing above on the host OS (win7, 64bit). I get the same results.

Br,
Szabolcs

Comment: I think you found a bug. I have tested this and the echo client exits immediately due to "The remote host closed the connection.". Connecting the client to echo.websocket.org works indeed. Watch for a patch :-)

Comment: The bug has been solved. I am waiting for the Qt CI configuration to be reconfigured for the patch to be merged. I suppose somewhere next week. In case you want to solve the bug for the time being: change SecureMode to NonSecureMode on line 77 in file qwebsocketserver_p.cpp.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this so fast! I tried the recommended fix, but that did not help in my case. Let's wait for the "official" patch.

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not happen in Qt 5.4 anymore. According to the comments above it was a bug in Qt and it seems to be fixed now, because in my environment the echoserver and echoclient work just fine.

My Environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04(64bit) running as a virtualbox guest on a win7 machine.
- Qt5.4(32bit)

Therefore I propose to mark this question as answered.